# I want to retrieve data in list from 2 different table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to retrieve data in list from 2 different table1 will having data A,B,C... where table2 will be having A-category,B-category list so on.. the id of table1 will in table2  for eg: A will be having the A-category list and B will be having B-category list and so on. I have tried the below code to retrieve. 
Like
A
A-cat
B
B-cat
C
C-cat and so on in a list.

```
 $qry1=mysql_query("select * from product");
        $qry2=mysql_query("select * from brand order by p_id");
        $row2=mysql_fetch_array($qry2);
        echo '<ul>';
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry1))
        {
        echo '<li><a href="a-z.php?">'.$row['product'].'</a>';
        echo '<ul>';
            while ($row2=mysql_fetch_array($qry2))
            {
                echo '<li><a href="a-z.php?">'.$row2['brand'].'</a></li>';
            }
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Can you please define in what manner you want your data and your table structure, how does it look

Comment: What output you get for this?

Comment: Under A-category itself all data from table2 is retrieving. But i need to display in A-category items of A and in B-category items of B has to display

Answer (score 0):

No need to rite an inner loop.

```
        $qry1=mysql_query("select * from product");
        $qry2=mysql_query("select * from brand order by p_id");

        echo '<ul>';
        while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($qry1))
        {
          echo '<li><a href="a-z.php?">'.$row1['product'].'</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '<ul>';
        while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($qry2))
        {
          echo '<li><a href="a-z.php?">'.$row2['brand'].'</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
```

OR(if you have the same no.of column for both result)

```
        $qry1=mysql_query("select * from product");
        $qry2=mysql_query("select * from brand order by p_id");

        echo '<ul>';
        while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($qry1) && $row2=mysql_fetch_array($qry2))
        {
          echo '<li><a href="a-z.php?">'.$row1['product'].'</a></li>';
          echo '<li><a href="a-z.php?">'.$row2['brand'].'</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
```